# Dataset with multiple coordinate notations (DMS, DD, etc.)

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I have an original dataset in Excel form with locations given in coordinates. However, the coordinate notation is not uniform. Some are in decimal form, some in degree and minute form. How do I harmonize these all into one, consistent notation? I do not care what the final notation system is, so long as I can plot them, as I intend to match these points with shapefiles later. I am attempting to do this in QGIS. An example subset is included below. All coordinates are in Virginia, meaning that some Longitude values should be negative, but are listed as positive (e.g., observation 4 in the table).

| Observation | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 38 30 03 | 77 58 51 |
| 2 | 39 1 22 | 77 29 54 |
| 3 | 38.8240 | -77.6322 |
| 4 | 37.269180 | 76.717710 |
| 5 | 38 31 40.48 | 77 17 11.86 |
| 6 | 37D 16 40 | 78D 23 55 |
| 7 | 38 47.77n | 37.66'w |
| 8 | 36 41.882 | w81 59.821 |
| 9 | 12189908 | 3452985 |
| 10 | 3655727 | 11774085 |

As you can see, there are multiple notational systems in use, some of them I have never seen before. I have tried to systematically identify them to split the data by identifying observations based on markers (does it have a period, a "w"), but I haven't been able to find a way to uniquely distinguish each coordinate type. I have ~25,000 observations, so brute force is not an option. If converting all of them into the same notation isn't possible, being able to systematically identify the notation type to split the data would be another way to get at it.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the excel dataset? I might first suggest figuring out what all notations you have and then convert them to one based on what format they have. You could do this in excel, but python might be a better option (pandas).

Comment: Are you saying that some of the coordinates that have negative values should not be negatives? And vice versu?

Comment: Please decide whether it is QGIS or R that you wish to ask about in this particular question. If it’s R then please include a code snippet that illustrates what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck.

Comment: @Binx My trouble is identifying, for each observation, what type of notation it is. I just have the coordinates, so I would need to automate a way to distinguish notation styles on my own. I don't know how to go about doing that. I do not have experience with Python. Some Longitude coordinates are positive when they should be negative. That's the only issue with negatives I have identified in the data.

Comment: I have no knowledge of how QGIS could "automatically" handle all these different notations. They should be in one that QGIS can handle. So I would suggest learning python for your task. Look into how to use `pandas` to read in your data. Then I would suggest using [`RegEx`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) to find the notation variations. Identify them with perhapes a unique identifier and then based on that identifier apply methods to convert to one notation.

Comment: For the negative values, you said that they should all be located in Virginia. So maybe find a shapefile boundary of Virginia and see which ones fall outside of the shapefile. Then try flipping the sign.